# Pycharm not clearing the git status of files

Tags: git, pycharm, push, branch

i created a local branch and did some mofications/additions and pushed the new changes, everyrthing working as expected, but after i push the files, normally the IDE `Pycharm` clears the status on the files, i mean the colors which usually mean that there are some new files, or new modifications.

but this doesnt happen on newly created branches, i did the following commands

- git checkout -b `branch-name`
- git add -A
- git commit -m "......."
- git push --set-upstream origin `branch-name`

[image: files status]

Comment: Can you right click on a folder and refresh the file panel?

Comment: Offhand this feels like a bug in the IDE.

Comment: thank you @GregBurghardt, I believe so because the files `color-status` will get cleared if i opened each `modified-file` click on revert changes which will remove my new changes that are committed before and then click `CTRL+Z` which basically undo revert changes,

Comment: doesn't make sense but this is what happens :) i think some bug in Pycharm or need a simple refresh

Comment: Please create an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IntelliJ doesn’t pick up Git changes that aren’t performed by IntelliJ itself. You can tell IntelliJ to refresh version control with **VCS → Refresh File Statuses**.